# How to optional routing parameter in Symfony2 on each level

Tags: php, symfony, routes, option-type

we are rewriting old hardcoded website to the new one based on Symfony2 framework.

We need to stay with old pattern in urls because of search engines. Our actual urls are:

- domain.tld/category/
- domain.tld/category/subcategory/

this is not problem but now the really optional parameters:

- we have some navigators in fulltext search like: locality, form, type, length
- all navigators has to be as 'nice url'
- each navigator in url has to be on one spot (for not duplication)

it means:

- domain.tld/category/subcategory/locality-prague/form-daily/type-a/length-2/ <-- THIS IS FULL ('a' or '2' is only for example)

but all of parts are optional, examples of correct url:

- domain.tld/category/form-daily/
- domain.tld/category/subcategory/type-a/length-2/
- domain.tld/category/locality-prague/length-2/

example of incorrect url:

- domain.tld/category/length-2/locality-prague/ <-- mixed parts of url (length is before locality)

So... is there any elegant solution how to resolve optional parameters on each slug position in Symfony2?

There is how would I do this in Nette Framework:

```
/[<category [a-z]>/][<subcategory [a-z]>/][locality-<locality [a-z]>/][form-<form [a-z]>/][type-<type [a-z]>/][length-<length [a-z]>/]
```

[] - this means optional and it will match correctly

Comment: How is the controller resolved?e.g: based on category alone or category and subcategory?eitherway one solution is to make all parameters optional and pass them all to controller then resolve which is which in the controller.It might be a little complicated if you want to resolve your controller on both category and subcategory.